# Json file reading function mysteriously returns null, in electron

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, file-io, electron

I'm writing an electron app that requires me to read from a file and parse its contents into a javascript object using jQuery, and I've been having trouble. At the moment myObject (see in code) is returning null, when it should be returning a live javascript object parsed from the json file. The code I'm using is below and may be worth pointing out that it is written in a renderer process. I'm pretty new to javascript so it could well be something obvious I'm missing.

```
loadObjectBtn.addEventListener('click', function loadObject(event){

    myObject = jsonParser('C:\\someFolder\\myApp\\myJsonFile.json')
    console.log(myObject)
    return myObject
})

function jsonParser(fileName){

    var jsonObj = null
    fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function (err,data){
        if(err){
            return console.log(err)
        }
        console.log("read from file successfully")
        jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
    }) 
    return jsonObj
}
```

Interestingly if I run the code with a break point on the line:

```
return jsonObj
```

in the function `jsonParser()`, the code seems to work and returns a proper value for `myObject`. Do any of you guys know why this might be, or have a suggestion for some alternative code?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.readFile` is an asynchronous function. What that means is, at the time your `jsonParser` executes and `return jsonObj;` is executed, it has not yet been initialized (this will happen later asynchronously when your callback to `fs.readFile` is invoked). That is why it is `undefined`

You can modify your `jsonParser` function to accept a callback which you can use to hand the parsed data back after it is done to your main function.

Sample:

```
loadObjectBtn.addEventListener('click', function loadObject(event){

    jsonParser('C:\\someFolder\\myApp\\myJsonFile.json',function(err, data){
        //Check for error
        if(err){
            // Handle error
            return;
        }
        // Data is available here
        console.log(data)
    })

})

function jsonParser(fileName, cb){
    cb = (cb && typeof cb === 'function' && cb) || function(){};
    fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function (err,data){
        if(err){
            // Error happened, call the cb function with the error as first argument
            cb(err)
        }
        //It worked, parse and hand the data back to the callback
        var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
        cb(null,jsonObj);
    }) 
}
```

[Handy link on understanding error first callbacks](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/)

EDIT:
Adding link shared by @Archer in the comments
[Asynchronous vs synchronous execution, what does it really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean)

An alternative (though generally discouraged) is [to use the synchronous version `fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options)

[Related Question on `readFile` vs `readFileSync`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjn792B7d7YAhWBbrwKHR4_AGIQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F17604866%2Fdifference-between-readfile-and-readfilesync&usg=AOvVaw14_Ao4nTWLNqIUcIomLF8l)

Comment: Brilliant Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is because `fs.readFile` is asynchronous, it will take some time before the data is available. That is why we pass a call back function to all async calls. Here is a small rewrite:

```
loadObjectBtn.addEventListener('click', function loadObject(event){
    jsonParser('C:\\someFolder\\myApp\\myJsonFile.json', printJSON)
})

function printJSON (jsonData) {
    console.log("read from file successfully");
    jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
    console.log(jsonObj);
}

function jsonParser(fileName, callback){
    var jsonObj = null;
    fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function (err,data){
        if(err){
            return console.log(err)
        }
        return callback(data)
    })
}
```